# how to update mysql database on the backend every hour

Tags: mysql

I have some basics with android development but I'm new to web development, and I want to build a MySQL database that gets data from different APIs, I don't want to do that on the client side.

So I'm looking for a solution to update the database from different APIs on the back end, so the clients can only connect to the database.

I have already figured out how to update the database on the client side, what I need is how to do it on a server and how I can run it every hour.

Comment: I have you thought of using cron job?

Comment: Rather depends what servers/hosting you have available to you - might be good to update the question to provide this background.

Comment: The other thing I would consider is whether you really want to do it once an hour, or whether pulling the data in response to a client request might be better - there are lots of things to take into account when taking such a decision (how long the APIs take, volumes, etc etc) but I am a bit nervous that you are /assuming/ scheduling it is the answer.

Comment: thank you for your responses. no I didn't know about cron job, now after i searched it i think it a good solution thank you :)

Comment: @MandyShaw i'm using a free hosting on 00webhost .com since I'm just testing for now i hop i have answered your question, could you please tell me how the type of the servers/hosting can help me

Comment: It's about how much access you have to tools like cron on your hosting - if you want to go down that route you'll have to check.

Comment: @MandyShaw well parsing json from the APIs takes some time, so i want the data to be ready in the database when a client request it, and since i don't know when the API is going to be updated i chose to do it every hour.

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense, but you are still going to need (in my view) to check that your free hosting lets you use cron to schedule jobs.

Comment: yes it does, thank you @MandyShaw that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script in any language *(for instance PHP or Python)* that gets the data you want and updates the database with it. You can then use a cron job to run that script every hour.